# View dismisses unintentionally in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

My goal is to have an array of structs that when tapped on an individual item, a change is made and passed up to the parent view but doesn't automatically dismiss my child view. I'm really not sure why the child view is automatically dismissing and how to prevent it. Here is my code for the ContentView.  Note that I have now updated the struct to Identifiable.

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  test
//
//  Created by Kevin McQuown on 3/7/22.
//

import SwiftUI

struct Person: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var patients: [Person]
    init() {
        var temp: [Person] = []
        for index in 0 ..< 3 {
            temp.append(Person(name: "\(index)"))
        }
        patients = temp
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 40) {
                ForEach($patients) { $patient in
                    NavigationLink("\(patient.name)") {
                        View2(patient: $patient)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct View2: View {
    @Binding var patient: Person

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("\(patient.name)") {
            ChangeNameView(patient: $patient)
        }
    }
}

struct ChangeNameView: View {
    @Binding var patient: Person
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            patient.name = "New Name"
        } label: {
            Text("Set New Name")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm just going to add this as a comment, not an answer because I don't have a satisfying description of *why* this is the case, but if you add `.isDetailLink(false)` to your `NavigationLink` in `ContentView`, you'll get the behavior you expect.

Comment: you are amazing. Thank you so much.

Comment: and I got rid of a lot of \.self references in my ForEach :-)